# Metadata Feature in Habitat Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, metadata, helix, sitecore-habitat

I am working on applying the Helix Design Principles in an existing Sitecore project. One thing that I haven't been able to understand was the Metadata Feature.

I used Sitecore Habitat and searching through Google as a reference but haven't been able to understand it there as well. I haven't been able to find a detailed resource/documentation to learn more about what it does, how it works and how I would implement it to a currently existing project.

I'm sure this is a really broad question but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Metadata will add tags to your page header section

ex

```
<title>site name</title>
<meta name="description" content="Description"/>
```

this will help you with [seo](http://www.wordstream.com/meta-tags)

to implement it you need to add PageMetadata to your page base template and siteMetadata to your site base template, and add PageMetadata view to placeholder in your layout header tag